# App Crash for C++/CLI DLL and Exe of x64 bit

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2017, clr

Just to showcase problem I have written a simple **DLL x64** of *"Hello world"* changed its property to **CLR** and **Calling its Function from an Exe** which is also x64 and property Changed to **CLR**.

But My **`exe`** prints the **`Output`** *"Hello World"* and  crashes every time and gives FAULT Module Name `KERNELBASE.dll`.

When I change Property of both to **NO CLR** it works perfectly fine. This happens only for x64 application not observed in x86 program.

I am using Visual Studio 2017 on Windows Server 2012.

It will be very helpful if someone can guide me to correct direction.

Details of App Crash

```
Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
  Application Name: consuming_using_clr.exe
  Application Version:  0.0.0.0
  Application Timestamp:    5b42fff3
  Fault Module Name:    KERNELBASE.dll
  Fault Module Version: 6.3.9600.17055
  Fault Module Timestamp:   532954fb
  Exception Code:   c0020001
  Exception Offset: 0000000000005bf8
  OS Version:   6.3.9600.2.0.0.16.7
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 8e72
  Additional Information 2: 8e72455f15a8480830570fcb3c4abf60
  Additional Information 3: f8d5
  Additional Information 4: f8d519c5149c6c561af747d4db7e910a
```

DLL dot.h file

```
// The following ifdef block is the standard way of creating macros which make exporting 
// from a DLL simpler. All files within this DLL are compiled with the DLLWINDOWSDESKTOPWIZARD_EXPORTS
// symbol defined on the command line. This symbol should not be defined on any project
// that uses this DLL. This way any other project whose source files include this file see 
// DLLWINDOWSDESKTOPWIZARD_API functions as being imported from a DLL, whereas this DLL sees symbols
// defined with this macro as being exported.
#ifdef DLLWINDOWSDESKTOPWIZARD_EXPORTS
#define DLLWINDOWSDESKTOPWIZARD_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define DLLWINDOWSDESKTOPWIZARD_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
#using<System.dll>
#include<iostream>
using namespace System;
using namespace std;
// This class is exported from the Dll_windows_desktop_wizard.dll
class DLLWINDOWSDESKTOPWIZARD_API CDllwindowsdesktopwizard 
{

public:
    CDllwindowsdesktopwizard(void);
    ~CDllwindowsdesktopwizard(void);
    void helloworld();

};
```

***DLL DOT CPP File ***

```
// Dll_windows_desktop_wizard.cpp : Defines the exported functions for the DLL application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Dll_windows_desktop_wizard.h"


// This is the constructor of a class that has been exported.
// see Dll_windows_desktop_wizard.h for the class definition

CDllwindowsdesktopwizard::CDllwindowsdesktopwizard(void)
{
}

CDllwindowsdesktopwizard::~CDllwindowsdesktopwizard(void)
{
}

void CDllwindowsdesktopwizard::helloworld()
{
    Console::WriteLine("Hello World");
}
```

**EXE Calling DLL Function**

```
#include<iostream>
#include "Dll_windows_desktop_wizard.h"
using namespace System;

int main()
{
    CDllwindowsdesktopwizard lv_obj;
    lv_obj.helloworld();
    return 0;
}
```

**dllMain.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: As i said it just says "Hello World". Console.writeline("Hello World")

Comment: 0xc0020001 is not an uncommon mishap when writing C++/CLI code.  It is highly specific, it tells you that your program is trying to execute managed code when the CLR has already shut down.  Otherwise very hard to debug, the debugger can't tell you much about it.  You need somebody to look at your code to pin-point the problem statement, Console::WriteLine() is not what causes it.

Comment: But my exe contains no more than Console::WriteLine().I have already Scanned the Server and found no corrupt file. Any Suggestion what could be the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got it.Came across this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ccthbfk8.aspx  as i was trying to remove the warning from my exe warning was 
`"warning:Calling managed 'DllMain': Managed code may not be run under loader lock,including the DLL entrypoint and calls reached from the DLL entrypoint"`

Comment: Tsk, tsk, tsk.  Update your question and show the DllMain function as well.

Comment: @HansPassant You can edit the title i will approve it.